# Is it possible to repeat a replacement string in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like to replace matches in Notepad++ using the Find and Replace window with n repeats of a certain character. Is there any "repeat" or "multiply" syntax to enter a character n times?

Example:

Find: `\s\s+`

Replace: `repeat("\r", 100) # replace it with 100 carriage returns`

Comment: Not sure about iterating via regex, but you could use a macro. Record the find and replace, then re-play the macro.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Notepad++ does have standard "Replace all" that replaces all instances of a pattern with the one you determine. AFAIK it also works with standard REGEX, which also should allow you to do the same. So can you please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679883/edit) your question to update it with an example of what exactly you're trying to find and replace, how exactly you're doing it, what exactly is your desired outcome and what exactly is the actual outcome?

Comment: Could you add an example before/after of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: There're no ways to do that with regex alone. You can use a Python script with PythonScript plugin. Are you open to such solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

This will replace 2 or more spaces with 100 carriage return, as explained in your question.

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example format.py):

```python
import re
def format(match):
    return 100 * "\r"
editor.rereplace('\s\s+', format)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> format)
- Done